# Mensagem de confirmação de saída

Tags: javascript

Estou trabalhando com criação de documentos, onde o usuário entra com as informações para que o documento possa ser gerado. Gostaria de que, se o usuário já tivesse escrito algo em algum dos campos e clicasse para sair da página, uma mensagem de confirmação de saída aparecesse na tela. Dei uma lida em outros tópicos aqui e descobri *onbeforeunload* do *JavaScript*, porém, não encontrei nada falando sobre como fazer a mensagem aparecer **somente** se houver algo nos campos. Meu código está assim:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit(){
        if((document.getElementsByName("interessado").value != "")||
           (document.getElementsByName("assunto").value != "")||
           (document.getElementsByName("assinatura").value != "")){
                return "Deseja realmente sair?";
        }
    }
```

Como posso criar uma mensagem de confirmação de saída apenas se existir alguma informação nos campos de texto?

Comment: Basta você contar, pega um `input` (ex), e faz um `length`, ai se for maior do que um, você avisa (chama a função), caso contrario...

Comment: Você acha que é mais eficiente do que o método que o Lucas citou, abaixo?

Comment: Eu acho que não muda muito, já que o conceito é o mesmo, ai vai depender do que você acha melhor, eu particulamente costumo contar, mas as duas soluções irá trazer um resultado bem similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByName` retorna um array, então você precisa checar o índice:

```
function confirmExit(){
    if( ( !document.getElementsByName("interessado")[0].value )||
        ( !document.getElementsByName("assunto")[0].value )||
        ( !document.getElementsByName("assinatura")[0].value )){
            return "Deseja realmente sair?";
    }      
}
```

Comment: A parte dos campos funcionou, mas quando clico no botão de enviar a mensagem aparece. Você pode me ajudar?

Comment: Claro, mas é para a mensagem não aparecer?

Comment: Quando eu clico no botão de enviar, o usuário é redirecionado para o documento gerado. Gostaria de que não aparecesse nesse caso.

Comment: No teste que fiz apareceu o dialog de confirmação antes do redirecionameto @LucasRamos

Comment: Sim, mas eu gostaria de que ele não aparecesse nesse caso, entende?

Comment: Se o usuário sair da página ou clicar no botão voltar, as informações ainda não estão salvas, então há risco de perde-las. Mas quando ele clica no botão enviar, as informações vão direto para o banco, então tem risco de perde-las.